# Converting an RGB to BGR for Torch Tensor in C++

Tags: pytorch, libtorch

I have a torch tensor of size H, W, 3. I can easily swap this in Pytorch with `image[:, :, [2,1,0]]`

However, in C++ Libtorch I cannot figure it out:

I tried:

```cpp
std::vector<long> index_vector = {0,1,2};
auto index_tensor = torch::from_blob((long*)(index_vector.data()), {3}, torch::kLong);
std::vector<at::indexing::TensorIndex> index;
index = {"...", "...", index_tensor};
img_tensor = img_tensor.index(index);
```

But it does not work

Comment: shouldn't `index_vector` be `{2,1,0}` instead of `{0,1,2}`?

Answer (score 1):

I would try using [`flip`](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/classat_1_1_tensor.html#_CPPv4NK2at6Tensor4flipEN2at11IntArrayRefE) on the third dimension:

```cpp
img_tensor = img_tensor.flip(2);
```

Comment: this performs a copy of the tensor, is it possible to have a view with a negative stride (-1) instead, starting from the end ? That would probably not be cache-friendly though

Comment: @trialNerror I'm not very familiar with the internals of pytorch. AFAIK, pytorch does not support "negative strides". Are you sure a copy is made?